# How could I dynamically change the variable in the hook function

Tags: python

The expectation is that `exception_sender` should be changed to `not default` 
But when the handleException function invoked,
excepthook is still  `default`

How could i change the value in b.py

## a.py

```
exception_sender = "default"

def handleException(excType, excValue, trace):
    notification.sender = exception_sender

def register_exception_sender(sender):
    exception_sender = sender

sys.excepthook = handleException
```

## b.py

```
import a
register_exception_sender("not default")

1/0
```

Comment: `global exception_sender` in the first line of `register_exception_sender()`. Right now you are setting local name which goes out of scope on function return.

Answer (score 0):

As bad as using the keyword `global` is, it could do the job for you here.

```
def register_exception_sender(sender):
    global exception_sender
    exception_sender = sender
```

`global exception_sender` tells Python to modify the `exception_sender` in the global space instead of just locally in the function. This global space is where `handleException` reads it from.

However if all your function is doing is setting that value, then you could also just do this in file `b.py`:

```
a.exception_sender = "not default"
```

That sets the name in the global space of `a` too, and is much more clean and readable.